# Update ckeditor manually xpages

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, custom-controls, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am updating the version of CKeditor manually in the notes domino, and when I will use in some xPages is giving error of lack of some plugins.

Where can I be configuring not to load these IBM plugins into CKeditor?

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is configured through a JavaScript object. Your best bet is to change the configuration is to use `XSP.addOnLoad(function() {...});` To get hold of the `CKEDITOR` object. My favorite technique to inspect those type of objects is to add one line into such a function:

`debugger;`.

It kicks in only when your Chrome developer tools are open and suspends JavaScript execution, so you can inspect the object. Some pointers how to **add** plugins can be found [in this snippet](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=rich-text-editor-nsf-custom-plugin-extension), removing items should work similar.

Hope this helps!